# xlwings with an error message about PYTHONPATH and interpreter

Tags: xlwings

I am wondering if there was anyone experiencing similar issue that I had.
I am trying to run main from my .py file on Mac OS and it shows the following message.

"sh:/Users/~

Permission denied"

I wish to delete the file path on both interpreter and PYTHONPATH but the directory entered previously keeps on showing. Does anyone know how to remove or reset or resolve this error? Thank you so much for your help!

[error message when run main was executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYpeH.png)

[directory entered not disappearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G56s.png)